# Java Switch - Returning to User Input

Tags: java, input, switch-statement, joptionpane

I've made a small program in Java:

```
        String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your grade?");
        switch (grade)
        {
            case "A":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got an A - Well done!");
                break;

            case "B":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a B - Very good!");
                break;

            case "C":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a C - Good!");
                break;

            case "D":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a D - Study better next time!");
                break;

            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid grade!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is - If the user inputs an invalid grade, the "Invalid grade!" message appears, and after pressing "OK" it just closes.

How can I make the program return to the input stage after the message of the invalid grade?

Comment: Use a while with a flag

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`do-while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop with a flag:

```
boolean wrongInput = false;

do {
    wrongInput = false; 
    String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your grade?");
    switch (grade)
    {
        case "A":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got an A - Well done!");
            break;

        case "B":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a B - Very good!");
            break;

        case "C":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a C - Good!");
            break;

        case "D":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a D - Study better next time!");
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid grade!");
            wrongInput = true;
    }

} while(wrongInput);
```

Comment: OK, Thank you very much, but I'm using the label method, which seems a little bit simpler to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `while` loop and a label:

```
loop: while (true) {

    String grade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your grade?");
    switch (grade)
    {
    case "A":
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got an A - Well done!");
        break loop;

    case "B":
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a B - Very good!");
        break loop;

    case "C":
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a C - Good!");
        break loop;

    case "D":
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got a D - Study better next time!");
        break loop;

    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid grade!");
    }
}
```